# Обновление без клика

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно переделать данный код, чтобы информация о введенных символах обновлялась без клика по полю.

**JavaScript:**

```
function length_check(len_max, field_id, counter_id) {
    var len_current = document.getElementById(field_id).value.length;
    var rest = len_max - len_current;
    if (len_current > len_max) {
        document.getElementById(field_id).value = document.getElementById(field_id).value.substr(0, len_max);
        if (rest < 0) {
            rest = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById(counter_id).firstChild.data = rest + ' / ' + len_max;
        alert('Максимальная длина содержимого поля: ' + len_max + ' символа(-ов)');
    } else {
        document.getElementById(counter_id).firstChild.data = rest + ' / ' + len_max;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea
    name="textarea"
    onclick="length_check(240, 'add_server_descr', 'counter')"
    value=""
    id="add_server_descr"
    class="flat-field add-server-descr"
    maxlength="240"
    autocomplete="off"
    type="text"
></textarea>
Осталось символов: <span id="counter">240 / 240</span>
```

Comment: Используйте onkeyup вместо onclick

Comment: я бы использовал input, и если нужна поддержка старых браузеров то paste

Comment: Не по вопросу: зачем использовать .firstChild, если Вы выбираете элемент по id? Он уже и так 1 в этой выборке... лишний код, ИМХО  
P.s: А вот если у Вас несколько элементов на странице с одним id - это плохо, не правильно и еще куча схожих наречий и прилагательных.

Comment: @fremail, спасибо, учту.